# ODBC to CSV File, Need to split a column up with Seperators from Select statement

Tags: sql, csv, odbc

In my CSV file I have columns with the following values:

```
[Location]
1001-AAA-JOE A BLOGS-AAAA0000
1002-BBB-Michael J Jackson-BBBB0000
1003-AAA-Lewis Hamilton-AAAA0000
```

I need to split this column up into sperate columns, this is easy with the fixed length fields IE the first 2 sections and the last 3, but the variable length field in the middle is proving to be difficult!

So in my examples above I would like to get a column called NAME with the values;

```
JOE A BLOGS 
Michael J Jackson 
Lewis Hamilton
```

Is this possible?

This is what I have so far in my select statement;

select * , 
Left([Location],InStr([Location],'-')-1) as SITENUMBER ,
Left((Mid([Location],InStr([Location],'-')+1)),InStr([Location],'-')-2) as Brand, 
left(right([Location],8),2) AS RegionCode,left(right([Location],6),2) AS AreaCode,
left(right([Location],4),4) AS HubCode 
from [CSVExport.csv]

Answer (score 0):

So, splitting the input string `location` into tokens using the hyphen as the separator, you want the 3rd token that you get.

You did not mention the DBMS you're using. ODBC can connect to anything: Oracle, Teradata, Vertica, SQL Server, Informix, Postgres, Ingres, Hive, you name it.

Let's be optimistic and guess that your DBMS supports the `SPLIT_PART()` function.

Then, try this:

```
WITH
input (location) AS (
          SELECT '1001-AAA-JOE A BLOGS-AAAA0000'
UNION ALL SELECT '1002-BBB-Michael J Jackson-BBBB0000'
UNION ALL SELECT '1003-AAA-Lewis Hamilton-AAAA0000'
)
SELECT 
  SPLIT_PART(location,'-',3) AS name
FROM input;

name
JOE A BLOGS
Michael J Jackson
Lewis Hamilton
select succeeded; 3 rows fetched
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, there is no DBMS so it's just ODBC to a CSV [ODBC TEXT DRIVER]  file, this is why I am struggling. So the SPLIT_PART function doesn't seem to work as I am getting an error "ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Text Driver] Undefined function 'SPLIT_PART' in expression.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example based on SQL Server. Hope can help you (you can use similar method with INSTR in your case).

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(LOCATION, 1,SEP1-1 ) AS SN
    ,  SUBSTRING(LOCATION, SEP1+1,SEP2-SEP1-1 ) AS BRAND
    ,  SUBSTRING(LOCATION, SEP2+1,SEP3-SEP2-1 ) AS NAME
    , left(right(LOCATION,8),2) AS RegionCode
    , left(right(LOCATION,6),2) AS AreaCode
    , left(right(LOCATION,4),4) AS HubCode
FROM (
    SELECT  CHARINDEX('-',LOCATION) AS SEP1 
    , CHARINDEX('-', LOCATION, CHARINDEX('-',LOCATION)+1 ) AS SEP2
    , CHARINDEX('-', LOCATION, CHARINDEX('-', LOCATION, CHARINDEX('-',LOCATION)+1 )+1) AS SEP3
    , LOCATION FROM (SELECT '1001-AAA-JOE A BLOGS-AAAA0000' AS LOCATION UNION SELECT '1002-BBB-Michael J Jackson-BBBB0000' UNION SELECT '1003-AAA-Lewis Hamilton-AAAA0000') Y
    ) X
```

Output:

```
SN                   BRAND                     NAME                                RegionCode AreaCode HubCode
-------------------- ------------------------- ----------------------------------- ---------- -------- -------
1001                 AAA                       JOE A BLOGS                         AA         AA       0000
1002                 BBB                       Michael J Jackson                   BB         BB       0000
1003                 AAA                       Lewis Hamilton                      AA         AA       0000
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple more options for you using substrings/charindex.

It may be best to convert to XML but will be quite a bit more code.

```
Create Table #table (record VARCHAR(50))
Insert Into #table
VALUES ('1001-AAA-JOE A BLOGS-AAAA0000'), ('1002-BBB-Michael J Jackson-BBBB0000'), ('1003-AAA-Lewis Hamilton-AAAA0000')

Select 
SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(record, CHARINDEX('-', record) + 5, 100) , 1, CHARINDEX('-', SUBSTRING(record, CHARINDEX('-', record) + 5, 100))-1) 'Name'
From #table
```

or

```
Select
SUBSTRING(x, 1, CHARINDEX('-', x) -1) 'Name'
From
(
    Select 
    SUBSTRING(record, CHARINDEX('-', record) + 5, 100) 'x'
    From #table
) y
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a custom CSV format using `odbcad32`, the ODBC data administration tool for Windows.

The file `location.asc` looks like this:

```
1001-AAA-JOE A BLOGS-AAAA0000
1002-BBB-Michael J Jackson-BBBB0000
1003-AAA-Lewis Hamilton-AAAA0000
```

In `odbcad32`, I added a new data source of type "Microsoft Access Text Driver". Configuring it, I specified the data directory for `location.asc`. Then I hit the [Options>>] button. In the appearing window, I added a new extension *.hsv. Then, I hit the [Define Format...] button. With `location.asc` marked, I changed the format in the drop down list from CSV delimited to custom delimited. And I specified the delimiter as `-` , the hyphen. I did not check the [ ] column name header tickbox. Then, I hit the [Guess] button on the right, and automatically got the fields F1 through F4. Then, I hit 3 times [Ok], to exit ODBCAD32 completely.

With that, I could just connect to the new ODBC data source. And then:

```
    SQL>select * from location.asc;
    F1   |F2 |F3               |F4
    1,001|AAA|JOE A BLOGS      |AAAA0000
    1,002|BBB|Michael J Jackson|BBBB0000
    1,003|AAA|Lewis Hamilton   |AAAA0000
```

Could that be your solution?